# What hot sauce should I use for Buffalo wings sauce?

Tags: substitutions, chicken, spicy-hot, chicken-wings

After watching "The Wing and I" in Good Eats and being the one that always ordered Buffalo wings (I no longer live in the US), I decide to give it a try. The recipe for the sauce is:

- butter
- garlic
- hot sauce

I wonder what exactly is hot sauce. Alton Brown said there are dozens of hot sauces. I tried to use plain tabasco but that doesn't work. Can I make my own?

Comment: I did the same thing, and yes, Tabasco doesn't really work that well. There are some good sellers on Ebay UK that can provide better hot sauces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The original Buffalo Wings are made with [Frank's RedHot Sauce](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00099XKXG). The original recipe is simply equal parts melted butter and hot sauce.

However, you truly can use just about whatever hot sauce you want in even greater ratios if you want more kick. There are also some distributors that specialize in spicy wing sauces. I recommend [Defcon 2](http://defconsauces.mybigcommerce.com/defense-condition-2-medium-wing-sauce/) if you are adventurous and enjoy a very nice kick of heat.

Comment: That's a great answer for the the main question... but what if I can't find any hot sauce? Can I make hot sauce from other sauces?

Comment: @Julio: Usually any place that sells tabasco will sell Frank's (*usually*).

Comment: @Aaronut Yes, I remember Frank's being popular, but I haven't been able to find it in Belgium. Tabasco, arrabbiata and curry ketchup, yes, chili or hot sauce, not yet :(

Comment: @julio: It's hard to imagine that you can't find hot sauce, but I've never been to Belgium. I _did_ tell you how to make wing sauce -- equal parts hot sauce and butter. I didn't understand your question to mean "How do I make hot sauce?". IMO that belongs in another question -- it has little to do with what hot sauce goes on buffalo wings.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll add another question. I was surprised at the beginning, but then remembered food in Europe is not spicy (in general). Tabasco is under foreign food :)

Comment: It may not be the most convenient, but if you can't find an appropriate hot sauce locally, you can surely find a vendor online.

Answer (score 3):

I make my own hot sauce fairly frequently using whatever chilli peppers are available locally. A good basic Frank's Red Hot Sauce recipe is here: http://www.food.com/recipe/copycat-franks-red-hot-sauce-494182

I add more peppers than it calls for and I end up with a thicker sauce, which is how I prefer it. You can use this recipe as a template and vary the ingredients to your own preferences. This basic recipe is easy to make and calls for hot peppers, garlic, vinegar, and salt - all ingredients that you should be able to get anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You make hot sauce by combining peppers and vinegar... you have to figure it out by personal taste past that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make your own. Or you can visit your local grocery store and pick from any of the likely dozens that are available. Franks Red Hot is popular in North America (I find it has no flavour, really).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a similar hot sauce to the one used in Buffalo wings, it is possible to make your own. A hot sauce like Frank's largely consists of dried cayenne peppers, soaked in vinegar, water, salt, and garlic. Put it in the blender until it's smooth.

Answer (score -2):

I.m not American so obviously have no idea but saw somewhere you can use sriracha which we can get in France.  If you have not had the original I doubt if you would know the difference :)

Comment: While I like sriracha, it s a very different flavor than Franks Red Hot or other similar hot sauces. Also, this doesn’t answer their question of what it is and how to make it